# Change entire gridview cell color from label ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Trying to figure out how to change the background color of a gridview cell when I have the label ID.

`<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="thisLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("thisLabel") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>`

`Label lbStdPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbStdPrice");
lbPrice.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;`

This only highlights the text. I want it to change entire cell color like:

`e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;`

Comment: That should work (the last line you wrote). There's something missing in your requirements. (Not sure what you mean by "when I have the label ID".)

Comment: @wazz With `e.Row.Cells[10].BackColor` the cell number is hard coded. If the grid's layout changes I will have to update the new cell number. With Label ID it doesn't matter if the layout changes. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the parent back to a TableCell and change the color.

```
Label lbStdPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("thisLabel");
TableCell cell = lbStdPrice.Parent as TableCell;
cell.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
```