# Change Gridview color on condition ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to `asp.net` and I have got a project which is so important to my career, if you guys help me out it would be awesome..

Here is the problem:
I am using this `gridview` code and I want to change the "ostatus" datafield color to green if the condition text is "Accepted" the thing is I have tried everything on internet used and changed more than 15 codebehind but I just can't get it to change the color it's just doesn't work.

Here is the `gridview` code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="srchuppan" UpdateMode="Always"><ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView5" Style="margin-bottom: 2%; width: 100%; font-family: '0 Nazanin'; direction: rtl; background-color: white; margin: auto; text-align: center;" CssClass="table table-bordered resgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="ردیف">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="یادداشت">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnpopup" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ydd") %>' Width="40" Height="40" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("cmcount") %>' />

            <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnpopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"
                CancelControlID="btnCancelpopup" EnableViewState="true" DropShadow="true" />

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" CssClass="alertBox backpic" BackColor="White" runat="server" Width="400px">
                <h1>یادداشت خود را بنویسید</h1>
                <p style="color: red; font-size: 12px">(<%# Eval("order_id") %>)</p>
                <hr />
                <textarea id="YY" class="form-control" rows="3" style="width: 80%; margin: auto; font-size: 16px" runat="server"></textarea>
                <hr />
                <asp:Button ID="Yadsrch" OnClick="Yadsrch_Click" CssClass="DokmeDefBlue" runat="server" Text="ثبت یادداشت" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelpopup" CssClass="DokmeDefRed" runat="server" Text="بستن" />
                <hr />
            </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="2%" DataField="order_id" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderText="کد سفارش" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="date1" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13px" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="تاریخ ثبت" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" DataField="name1" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="نام سفارش دهنده" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" DataField="your_tell" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="تلفن" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="P_name" ItemStyle-Font-Size="10" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="محصول" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="pay_amount" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="قیمت" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ostatus" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="وضعیت" />
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="تخفیف">
        <ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change entire gridview cell color from label ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390716/change-entire-gridview-cell-color-from-label-id)

Comment: No time for me to put together a complete answer right now, but look up [`DataKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx), which you should use to hold your condition field. Then look at [`RowDataBound` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform comparison and styling,

Comment: if I wasn't new to asp.net I would do that man, but thanks for the hints I will look into them but I don't think I can make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "BoundField" you should use "TemplateField" for ostatus

```
// replace this line
<asp:BoundField DataField="ostatus" ItemStyle-Font-Size="13" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14" HeaderText="وضعیت" />

// use this
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="وضعیت">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span style="color: <%# (Eval("ostatus").ToString() == "Accepted") ? "green" : "black;" %>">
            <%# Eval("ostatus") %>
        </span>     
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have used ternary operator to check ostatus is "Accepted" or not if it is then it changes the text color to green using in line CSS as style="color:green;" Or style="color:black;" otherwise. Eval method is similar to BoundField tag which access the bounded data source value.

There are many ways to achieve this, as per your current situation this one seems simple.

Hope it helps

Comment: Dude, you just saved my job.. I wish you the best that all this world could give